# How to schedule/trigger jenkins job based on input parameters?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have created a jenkins job, which is parameterized. Parameters namely **HH, MM, Day** and etc. So, This build is concurrent enabled. My idea is, whenever this job is triggered with the specific **HH, MM, DAY** values, the child job of this job has to be scheduled at that particular time.

I think, Build Periodically doesn't work for this.
How about Parameterized Scheduler ?
Could you please help me with the feasible solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to schedule the job with a Groovy script, by using [hudson.model.Queue.schedule()](http://hudson-ci.org/javadoc/hudson/model/Queue.html#schedule(hudson.model.Queue.Task,%20int,%20java.util.List)) method.

```java
def job = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getJob("myjob")
// You need a dummy parameter to avoid duplicate job cancellation
def now = System.currentTimeMillis()
def params = new StringParameterValue('DUMMY', String.valueOf(now))
def paramsAction = new ParametersAction(params)
def cause = new hudson.model.Cause.UpstreamCause(currentBuild)
def causeAction = new hudson.model.CauseAction(cause)
// Here you need to define the quiet period according to your paramters
def quietPeriod = 12345
def waitingItem = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.queue.schedule(job, quietPeriod, causeAction, paramsAction)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution that I can think of is to use some scripts or shell script to check for specific time and create a file  if the specified criteria is met.

Later you can use conditional Trigger plugin to trigger the other job if the file exists Note: you might have to delete the file after triggering the job.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin